# How to compute Upper Confidence Bound Properly In Multiarmed Bandit Problem

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

[image]

I'm currently working on implementing the Upper Confidence Bound (UCB) algorithm for the Multiarmed Bandit Problem, but I'm encountering some difficulties with the computation. Here's what I've understood so far and where I'm stuck:

In the Multiarmed Bandit Problem, we have a set of slot machines (arms), each with an unknown probability distribution of yielding rewards. The goal is to devise a strategy to maximize the total reward accumulated over a series of pulls.

One common approach is the UCB algorithm, where the idea is to balance between exploiting arms that have yielded high rewards so far and exploring arms that haven't been explored much yet.

What I've Done:

- I've initialized each arm's parameters, such as the number of times it has been pulled and the total reward obtained from it.
- I understand that the UCB formula typically involves a term for exploitation (mean reward) and a term for exploration (confidence interval), usually represented as UCB = mean_reward + exploration_term where exploration_term is typically proportional to sqrt(log(total_pulls) / arm_pulls).

**My Issue:**
Despite understanding the concept, I'm struggling with the implementation of the UCB formula, particularly with determining the appropriate values for mean_reward and
exploration_term. Here are my specific questions:

- ```
    How do I correctly calculate the mean reward for each arm?
  ```
- ```
    How should I properly compute the exploration term, and what should I use for total_pulls and arm_pulls in the formula?
  ```
- ```
    Are there any common pitfalls or mistakes to avoid when implementing the UCB algorithm?
  ```